# Programming C++ on OSX in Macbook pro

Tags: c++, macos

I'm thinking of getting a new laptop. Is OSX C++ programmer friendly? I mainly use gedit, gdb, g++, meld, ddd (gdb front end), valgrind and RabbitVCS (svn) in Ubuntu. Does OSX have equivalent softwares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Mac OS X works well for many programmers. As for the specific software you mentioned:

- You can get `gedit` for Mac OS X.
- `gdb` is included with Xcode.
- `g++` is also included with Xcode.
- It looks like Meld [has a Fink package](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/meld).
- I was able to compile and run `ddd` successfully.
- When I tried it quite a while ago, Valgrind did not work, but I think the issues have been fixed now (see Michael Anderson's comment).
- RabbitVCS will work if you install a supported file manager. As far as I know, Finder is not supported.

Comment: I was just going to point out that Xcode's g++ is a Clang/LLVM combo by default rather than the GCC probably supplied by Ubuntu (with an LLVM+GCC alternative still available for the time being). It's fully C++ conformant but macports.org can supply GCC if the poster really wants to stick to exactly the same stack.

Comment: Valgrind now works nicely on OS X - or it least it does for me.

Comment: @Michael Could you please let us know how did you manage to install Valgrind on OSX?

Comment: I built it from source. I'm using valgrind-3.6.0 and am not using fink or any other package manager.. I'm also on 10.5 which means gcc 4.0.1  rather than 10.7 .. but I am on a 64b macbook pro.

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS X complies with the Single UNIX Specification and, consequently, is pretty programmer friendly. That said, some additional niceties on Linux that go above and beyond the spec may not be available on Mac OS X. Also, some Linux applications that rely on Gnome or KDE may not be available or might not work 100% on Mac OS X. As an example, GEdit is available for Mac OS X, but is extremely buggy.

That said, there are also many tools and utilities for programmers that are available on Mac OS X that are not available on Linux. For example, on Mac OS X, I use Xcode instead of GEdit, and Xcode is arguably far superior to GEdit as a code editor. Sadly, Mac OS X has no RabbitVCS equivalent.

You should have no problem with GCC, g++, etc. as those are all available through the Xcode package that is provided for free with Mac OS X. There is also a project called [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), which brings many opensource packages that are available for Linux to Mac OS X. It provides an interface that is similar to apt-get (except it installs from source rather than from binaries) for installing those packages. I have Snow Leopard and have not had any trouble with MacPorts; however, be aware that the MacPorts page currently lists a number of packages that do not yet work in Lion, so some things might not work with a new MacBook until the port maintainers have patched their packages to work with Lion.

Comment: +1: This made me smile "...complies with the Single UNIX Specification and, consequently, is pretty programmer friendly." :-)

Comment: Note: XCode features gcc 4.2.x because subsequent versions are GPL v3 and Apple does not wish to publish its code.

Comment: What is the tool OSX programmers use to fetch code from subversion?

Comment: Found this: http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitvcs-devel/browse_thread/thread/f6ccd4d6f582f040?pli=1

Comment: xcode has build in subversion. personally i use cornerstone which is really advanced with branching and merging support. there is also versions which works nice for basic svn stuff. both costs money and were on sale when I last checked

Comment: @andromeda, you can use svn from the commandline, there just isn't a nice UI for it.

Answer (score 1):

The GCC toolchain is the very same, we've found only 1 difference to Linux (Ubuntu) in a 10k line source (server stuff), some include was in different place.